# Pip command for updating python3-matplotlib 1.3.1-1ubuntu5

Tags: ubuntu, github, matplotlib, pip

How can I update my package "python3-matplotlib 1.3.1-1ubuntu5" using pip and github? I need to update because I have some rendering problems in Ubuntu 14.04.

See: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2976 for more details.

I used:

```
 sudo pip3 install matplotlib --upgrade
```

but that didn't upgrade the right package (I don't really know).

Comment: I suspect you are mixing system installed files with pip installed files which can only lead to madness.

Comment: Ok. It might be better to wait for the repository to update. Thanks!